# Variance - why is the denominator squared?

Tags: statistics, variance, linear-regression

The question asks to calculate the variance for $\hat{\beta}$. I've checked the solutions and I don't know why the denominator is squared. What formula is that?

$$
Var\left(\hat\beta\right) 
= Var\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\bar{x})^{2}}\right) 
= \frac{Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})Y_i\right)}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)^2\right)^{2}}
$$

The full question, with the initial information about the data:

> [image: Question 1]

Comment: $\text{Var}(aX)=a^2\text{Var}(X)$

Comment: @AndréArmatowski thank you! It makes sense now!